# Rather use a sample of a population or analyze a whole population but smaller?

Tags: sample, validation

I am validating an automated surveillance program. It is about infection incidence on a hospital ward. I could easily check if the small list of infections produced by the automated surveillance includes all patients that really have an infection (in other words; calculate the positive predictive value). The list of patients not labeled as infected by the program is a whole lot longer. This brings me to two questions:

1. I'm not sure if I should get a sample size of the infection-negatives and check if they are indeed infection-negative. Or should I get a smaller (for example 6 month cohort with 300 patients) and check all of them?
2. Is combining methods even an option (check all of the positive-labeled patients and only a sample of the negative-labeled patients)?

Thanks in advance,
Suzanne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to say about the system. Taking an unbiased sample of all patients regardless of the prediction will get you unbiased population-level statistics. You can calculate things like overall accuracy and prevalence of the predicted positive/negative classes.

If you have a rare infection, however, a small sample size may not adequately characterize the positive class. If the infection is only in 1% of cases, you'd only expect 3 cases in a cohort of 300, which is too few to give you any kind of confidence in your PPV estimate.

It is a reasonable approach to check all the predicted positives as well as a sample of the predicted negatives, as that will give you enough samples in both to get a good estimate of PPV and NPV. If you take this approach, however, you should not try to say anything about prevalence of the classes or overall accuracy, since your sample population is no longer representative of the overall population. You can still do within-class statistics (PPV/NPV), but be careful with anything that's calculated over both classes, since your sampling will have skewed the prevalence of those classes.

I think the combined approach of testing all predicted positives and a sample of predicted negatives is the way to go, particularly if your positive class is rare and would require a very large random sample to adequately characterize.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it has been very helpful.
The only thing I don't completely understand is what you mean by this: "you should not try to say anything about prevalence of the classes or overall accuracy, since your sample population is no longer representative of the overall population."
Does that mean that I won't be able to say anything about for example incidence of the infections? I understand if that is the case, that will be another study once the method is validated. As long as I can still make conclusions on test measurements such as sensitivity, specificity and NPV/PPV.

Comment: @SuzanneGreup Right, if you take all of your predicted positives and some sample of predicted negatives, you could wind up with any ratio of positives to negatives depending on how big your sample of negatives is - you can't infer anything about the natural incidence of predicted positives there, since it will depend heavily on how you sampled the negatives. You can still compute within-class statistics, but anything that relies on an unbiased sampling (like overall accuracy) won't work - you'd need to randomly sample the population without regard for their predicted status to do that.